# SwiftUI: Styling TabbarView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Can someone tell me how to style my TabbarView and TabItems

I want:

1. Gradient on selected TabItem (Setting accentColor to orange, but want gradient)
2. Corner radius on top-left and top-right corner on TabbarView
3. Size on image in TabItem, and placement (top, leading, trailing, bottom paddings)
4. TabbarView should be solid, the background color on the containing view changes the backgroundcolor as TabbarView background color isn't the same when containing view is black or white.

Current code:

```
struct TabbarView: View {
    @State var selectedView = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedView) {
            Text("Page 1")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
            }
            .tag(0)
            Text("Page 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
            }
            .tag(1)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .accentColor(.orange)
    }
}
```

Image:

[image]

If you only know part of the question, please let me know :)

Thanks!

Comment: Appearance of TabView is not customizable. To achieve the effect described you have to implement your own.

Comment: When using a system Image in a tabbar, I recommend to apply the `.imageScale(.large)` modifier on that Image.